# How do I combine two text files line by line with Python?

Tags: python, text-files

I have two text files. Both files contain coordinates that I would like to be combined into one file that I could plug into a line of best fit calculator. However, I can't seem to figure out how to combine them.

File 1

```
123
154
123
312
241
151
```

File 2

```
7832910
4839822
5732910
4832910
1875821
3632910
```

How do I combine them into 1 text file with commas separating them. For example:

File 3

```
123, 7832910
154, 4839822
123, 5732910
312, 4832910
241, 1875821
151, 3632910
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the more suited for this is certainly to use `paste` in your terminal:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | sed 's/\t/, /g' > file3
```

Still if you want to use python:

```
with open("file1") as f1, open("file2") as f2, open("out","w") as f3:
    for x,y in zip(f1,f2):
        f3.write(x.strip()+", "+y.strip()+'\n')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good! Think about accepting the answer if that helped ;) (gray tick top left)